# Virtual наследование

Tags: c++

Добрый день!

1) Есть:

```
class A;
class B: virtual public A;
class C: virtual public A;
class D: public B, public C;
```

В общем классика, конструкторы вызываются как: А В С D.

2) Делаем так:

```
class A;
class B: public A;
class C: virtual public A;
class D: public B, public C;
```

Как я понимаю, воспринимает это класс D: A B (v)A C D. virtual A переносится на первое место и получаем вызов конструкторов: (v)A A C B D.

3) Теперь делаем так:

```
class A;
class D: public А, virtual public A;
```

Как я понимаю, воспринимает это класс D: A, (v)A. вызов конструкторов: (v)A A. - это по логике предыдущего примера, и так нельзя, я могу согласиться с этим, хорошо. Но вот вернемся к первой классике, как я понимаю видит это класс D: (v)A B (v)A C D. Пусть потом виртуалы пойдут на первое место и будет: (v)A (v)A B C D. По логике моего 2-oго примера. Такие дела, помогите разобраться с очередностью вызовов конструктора в виртуальном наследовании. Опишите хотя бы, почему в первой классике вызывается только один базовый конструктор и где у потомков прописано, что так и нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: ссылки на подробное описание- приветствуются

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10534228/276994

Comment: можно сказать, что класс D должен знать инфу о виртуальных наследованиях в цепочке наследования и он сам вызывает их и должен о них знать инфу, например: для вызова нужного нам конструктора конструктора. Т.е. в первом примере клас D вызывает класс A. И на этом работа с классом А заканчивается. Класс B - уже не вызывает класс А. Но если бы у класса В не было наследников, то он бы вызвал класс А. Вопрос такой, у Класса В есть флажок какой-то, что конструктор класса А уже был вызван? да/нет)

Comment: @fortunado: ваша мысленная модель поведения виртуальных конструкторов не вполне верна. Это не `B` вызывает (или там решает, вызывать или нет) конструкторы его виртуальных базовых классов, это most derived -- `A`. Потом вызываются как обычно рекурсивно конструкторы _невиртуальных_ классов.

Comment: @fortunado: вот вам иллюстрация: <http://ideone.com/ZdYQE3>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mi-vi-ctor-order.html):

> Прежде всего вызываются конструкторы *виртуальных* базовых классов по всему дереву наследования. Их порядок соответствует обходу дерева наследования в глубину слева направо (более правая ветка дерева соответствует более позднему появлению в исходниках).
>
> После того, как все конструкторы виртуальных базовых классов отработали, порядок вызова конструкторов -- от базового класса к производному. Легче всего представить себе так: в самом начале конструктора порождённого класса компилятор делает неявный вызов конструкторов *невиртуальных* базовых классов (кстати: многие компиляторы именно так и делают в реальности). Например, если класс `D` порождён от `B1` и `B2`, сначала выполняется конструктор `B1`, затем конструктор `B2`, затем конструктор `D`. Это правило применяется рекурсивно: например, если `B1` в свою очередь порождён от `B1a` и `B1b`, и `B2` порождён от `B2a` и `B2b`, результирующий порядок конструкторов такой: `B1a`, `B1b`, `B1`, `B2a`, `B2b`, `B2`, `D`.
>
> Порядок вызова `B1` и `B2` (или `B1a` и `B1b`) определяется порядком, в котором эти базовые классы появляются в тексте декларации порождённого класса, а не в порядке, в котором инициализаторы стоят в списке инициализации конструктора порождённого класса.